# Java Inheritance, Two subclasses of the same class

Tags: java, inheritance, subclass

Some context:
I have a two different classes (Client and ClientAuth) that both extend the same abstract class, NetworkingAbstract (i'll call it NA). This last class has three different protected static class variables with the following types: a Socket, an InputStream and an OutputStream.

I create a new ClientAuth object inside the Client class. The ClientAuth object calls a method that
initializes the NetworkingAbstract class variables, InputStream and OutputStream. Then, when the method returns, when I access those variables (inside the Client class), they have the same values that were attributed to them inside the ClientAuth object!

This actually suits my needs, but I don't understand why this happens!

Shouldn't those class variables (OutputStream and InputStream) be independent between Client and ClientAuth despite the fact that they both extend the same class?? Or is it that because they both extend the same class, they share the values??

I hope I made my question clear enough..

Comment: there is always only one instance of a static variable. that's the definition of static.

Comment: static variables are shared between all instances of the class and its subclasses. There is basically no inheritance or overriding of static variables they are not like 'class variables' you may be used to from other languages.

Comment: Please do not describe your classes, show the code reduced to the minimum necessary to communicate your question (see [mcve])

Comment: It sounds like you need to explain your reasoning behind creating your variables as static.

Comment: I don't know why you're being downvoted; Did either of these answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

> This last class has three different protected static class variables with the following types: a Socket, an InputStream and an OutputStream.

A static variable is one that's associated with a class, not individual objects of that class.

You need not use static variables if you want them to be unique to each object.

Answer (score 0):

Static properties on classes are shared between all its instances.
For that reason that properties all called class' properties.

Read this [java-static-methods-variables-static](http://crunchify.com/java-static-methods-variables-static-block-and-class-with-example/).